Telegram Bot 403 forbidden for url error (using requests.post)
I have tried Telegram bots API responds 403 Forbidden but this did not work for me. What am I missing?? I get a "403 Client Error: Forbidden for url:" in my Python IDE.
import requests
def send(text, chat_id, api_token):
    params = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': text, 'parse_mode': 'HTML'}
    url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{api_token}/sendMessage'
    resp = requests.post(url, params)
    resp.raise_for_status()

send('Hello World!', chat_id, api_token)

Telegram:
I created a Telegram bot, found chat_id, and api_token, which is chat_id followed by semicolon, then the rest of the api_token i.e. 89123:sufhsfhai
I have started a conversation with the Telegram bot.
Is my code correct? Do I need to setup Telegram bot more?

'api_token, which is chat_id followed by semicolon' thats not true, use the token as the Botfather shows.

Yes, I am using the token exactly as the Botfather.
It looks like a bunch of numbers, semicolon, then some text: i.e.
89123:sufhsfhai

Yea that should work. I've tested your code with my token and chat Id and it worked fine!

Thanks for confirming my code works...maybe it's a Telegram bot setting somewhere. I'll also recheck chatid

Turns out I made a typo in the chat_id. Thanks so much for testing my code, helped me realize the code itself was ok.
